# android SQLITE database app crashes oncreate when it runs the getAllComments() method

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am trying to make an app which you can enter two comments into the database at once, it keeps crashing oncreate when it tries to add all the comments to the list. any help would be most appreciated. thank you in advance.

**onCreate**

```
 @Override

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.comments);
    etComm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etComment);
    etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    //Create a new data manager objects
    datasource = new CommentsManageData(this);
    datasource.open(); //Create or open the database
    List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();
    // use the SimpleCursorAdapter to show elements in a ListView
    ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

 //This retrieves data from the database and puts it into an ArrayList
  public List<Comment> getAllComments() {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
        //Retrieve all comments - returns a cursor positioned 
        //over first item in the results     
        Cursor cursor = database.query(CommentsSQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
          allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst(); //Just in case it wasn't there already
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Comment comment = cursorToComment(cursor);
            comments.add(comment);//Add the comment

            cursor.moveToNext(); // move to the next item in results
        }
        cursor.close(); // make sure to close the cursor
        return comments;
      }
```

**SQLiteOpenHelper:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
/*
 * This class is responsible for creating the database. 
 * It also defines several constants for the table name and the table columns
 * This could be a private class within CommentsDataSource
 */
public class CommentsSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {//Note subclass

      public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
      public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
      public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";
      public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
      private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

      // Database creation sql statement
      private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
          + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + 
          COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
          COLUMN_COMMENT + " integer not null, "+
          COLUMN_NAME + "integer not null)";

      public CommentsSQLiteHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }
      //Must override this method
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
      }

      //The onUpgrade() method will simply delete all existing data and re-create the table.
    //Must override this method
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(CommentsSQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMMENTS);
        onCreate(db);
      }

    } 


   comment object code 

public class Comment {
      private long id;
      private String comment;
      private String name;


      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public String getComment() {
        return comment;
      }

      public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
      }

      public String getname() {
            return name;
          }

     public void setname(String name) {
            this.name = name;
          }
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-28 04:10:35.998: E/SQLiteLog(1332): (1) no such column: name
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332): Process: cct.mad.lab, PID: 1332
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cct.mad.lab/cct.mad.lab.CommentsApp}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, comment, name FROM comments
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, comment, name FROM comments
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at cct.mad.lab.CommentsManageData.getAllComments(CommentsManageData.java:33)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at cct.mad.lab.CommentsApp.onCreate(CommentsApp.java:22)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-28 04:10:36.068: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Can you provide the logs

Comment: Yes, if it crachs, you have the errors in red in the logcat console

Comment: added error log cat in post above

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make changes to your database structure make sure to increment your Database Version to call `onUpgrade` where you should drop the old database structure and callback `onCreate` to reconstruct the database with the changes.

Comment: iv tried incrementing my database version it still says name does not exist

Comment: Try using `@Override` before your `onCreate` and `onUpgrade` methods. Then increment your `DATABASE_VERSION` again and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

The logcat you posted, says no such column "name" which means that your database table "TABLE_COMMENTS" which has column with title "name" is not created successfully. And from your CommentsSQLiteHelper class, you are creating your table like this:

```
// Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + 
      COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
      COLUMN_COMMENT + " integer not null, "+
      COLUMN_NAME + "integer not null)";
```

Here, if you'll observe there is no space between COLUMN_NAME & start of "integer not null" so it is clearly taking it as single string column name with no data type.

> See here -> COLUMN_NAME + "integer not null)"; (No space before start of datatype integer)

Hence, workaround is to put space before start of " integer not null". Copy paste below code:

```
 // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + 
      COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
      COLUMN_COMMENT + " integer not null, "+
      COLUMN_NAME + " integer not null)";
```

> UPDATE: As you are using string(text) in your "comment" & "name" field change datatype of COLUMN_COMMENT & COLUMN_NAME from integer to text(string).

Use below code:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + 
      COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
      COLUMN_COMMENT + " text not null, "+
      COLUMN_NAME + " text not null)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is: "no such column: name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, comment, name FROM comments".

The column name does not exists in your DB.

Furthermore, you coded this:

```
  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + 
      COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
      COLUMN_COMMENT + " integer not null, "+
      COLUMN_NAME + "integer not null)";
```

As you want to store comments, why to use integer ? it should be text like this:

```
  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + " (" + 
      COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
      COLUMN_COMMENT + " text, "+
      COLUMN_NAME + " text)";
```

Comment: ContentValues values = new ContentValues();//Stores a set of values that can be processed
     values.put(CommentsSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, comment);//Adds the comment to the set
     values.put(CommentsSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, name);
     long insertId = database.insert(CommentsSQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS, null,
         values); //insert the values created above into the database
     Cursor cursor = database.query(CommentsSQLiteHelper.TABLE_COMMENTS,
         allColumns, CommentsSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
  null, null, null);

Comment: public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";

Comment: how do you build your allColumns variable ?

Comment: private String[] allColumns = { CommentsSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, CommentsSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT, CommentsSQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME};

Comment: Can you provide the entire code of CommentsSQLiteHelper ? I think you have forgotten the COLUMN_NAME creation

Comment: Your code looks good. Can you update your variable DATABASE_VERSION to 2 and retry

Comment: iv tried upgrading my version it still says the name does not exist

Comment: Can you provide your Comment object code ? You are using integer for column name and comment which has no sense. It should be string

Comment: See my answer above, you use integer in db to store comment and name but in your java object, you use string

Comment: Can you increment your DATABASE_VERSION again and retry my DATABASE_CREATE code, there was a mistake.

Answer (score -2):

This seems simple enough.

You have an error stating that the column doesn't exist in your database.

This is commonly caused by you changing the database, after it was already created in your android environment.

You can remove this by uninstalling the app. and reinstalling it, which would effectively create a new database and should move you on to a working version.

Let me know if this didn't help.